# kotlin Springboot mockito integration test - EntityManger

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockito, integration, hibernate-entitymanager

How to mock the EntityManger in springboot mockito integration test

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = [EntityManager::class],
    properties = [
    "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
]
```

Should i put EntityManager in the classes or i should to mock it differently

Comment: I had similar issue, I added the class in SpringBootTest classes like you did and also add @MockBean
    lateinit var someClass: Class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I delete the EntityManager from the classes and i forget it from my mocke's class beacause i use JdbcAggregateOperations in the JPA layer.

My new configuration for the integration test is simply like this

```
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = [],
    properties = "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"])
 class DemoApplicationTests(@Autowired val restTemplate: TestRestTemplate,
                       @Autowired private val repository: UserRepository) {`
```

thank you